# Mass removal of materials with active F option

Tags: materials

In my projects I have plenty of materials with active F option (bpy.data.materials["name"].use_fake_user). Manually removing them one by one is horrible. What is the quick way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove fake user in Outliner in **Orphan Data** mode:

[image]

For complite remove materials if they haven't users, press **Purge All** button